# How to override default status line with airline

Tags: vimrc

I am using airline for vim status. However the problem is that the default status line is displayed as well.

Could someone please let me know how to disable this default status line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thats not a status line; it’s vim’s command line (for ex commands) and it’s also where messages are displayed). I think you can control which messages are displayed; however, you cannot get rid of that line.

Comment: More to follow when I have time